# What is the Laplace transform of this function

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of the time domain signal below:

[image]

The signal V(t) starts from zero and increases with a slope **m** and after **t1** seconds reaches to constant value **a**.

How can this function be written in s domain?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: It is a continuous function though?

Comment: a ramp which reaches to a constant after t1 seconds with a slope m.

Comment: it is continuos. You can calculate its Laplace transform via the definition.

Comment: I want to model a circuit with such switch source and solve it. But I cannot transform this to s domain

Comment: In other words what is V(s) for this given V(t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $V(t) = mt$ for $0\leq t \leq t_1$ and $V(t) = a$ for $t > t_1$.
The Laplace transform can be computed via its definition 
$$\mathcal{L}[V(t)](s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}V(t)e^{-st}dt = \int_{0}^{t_1}mte^{-st}dt + \int_{t_1}^{\infty}ae^{-st}dt$$ $$=-\frac{mt_1e^{-st_1}}{s}+m\frac{1-e^{-st_1}}{s^2}+ \frac{ae^{-st_1}}{s}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just take the derivative of $V(t)$, its expression is very simple and so is its transform. Then all you need is to know  how the transform of the integral is expressed in terms of the transform of the integrand.

Comment: Woah, this is a cool method. I never really thought about applying the laplace transform properties like that

Comment: Well, glad for the appreciation. It looks like you are studying to become (or are just a fresh) engineer: if so, you have better to get accustomed to solve problems like this (among others) in the .. *engineering way*!

Comment: by the way .. did you think that an even better way is to differentiate **twice**?

Answer (score 0):

We want to calculate the Laplace transform of $V(t)$. It is easy to calculate it directly from the definition:
$$\int_0^\infty V(t)e^{-st}\text{d}t=\int_0^{t_1}mt e^{-st}\text{d}t+\int_0^\infty ae^{-st}\text{d}t=m\int_0^{t_1}t e^{-st}\text{d}t+a\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\text{d}t$$

The first integral can be solved using integration by parts and the other one can be computed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Laplace transform definition:

$f(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st} dt$

Your function is $f(t) = mt$ from 0 to $t_1$ and $f(t) = a$ from $t_1$ to $\infty$, so:

$f(s) = \int_0^{t1} mt*e^{-st} $ $dt + \int_{t1}^\infty a*e^{-st}$ dt.

Comment: Isn't $f(t) = mt$ from $0$ to $t_1$?

Comment: Whoops, typo on my part. You're right. Fixing...

Comment: why dont you write the final result in terms of s? why did you leave it with integrals? isnt integral of e^-st easy? is there a reason you left it like this way?

Comment: I'll invoke the awful phrase: "It's trivial and I left it up to the reader". In other words I just left it since it's easy for you to do.

Comment: second part is easy, first part is the integral of t*e^-st i have to refresh my calculus..